# __dirname doesn't work in a regex

Tags: regex, node.js

I am trying to remove __dirname from a directory I need to copy (recursively). I gather information about the problem:

```
console.log(typeof __dirname); // string
console.log(__dirname); // c:\test
```

I need to create the regex from a string I get from the program. Therefore I must use `RegExp(myString)`. I do a reality check on jsfiddle to make sure the right way to escape \ is with \/ [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3QeQ/3/).

I run the code in the browser and it works. I run the code in node.js and it does not work. I take this to the [extreme](http://i.troll.ws/2edd5db6.png) by trying to remove `RegExp(__dirname)` from __dirname.

If you have a string `var s = __dirname.toString() + "myOtherPath/a.cat"` how do you remove the __dirname part of the string from s?

Comment: why can't your just use replace or substring(dirname_length)?

Comment: im not sure if the paths i use will be different from the paths my server uses. if they use paths with different lengths it would break.

Comment: Can you show your actual code where you are using `new RegExp`?

Comment: http://i.troll.ws/2edd5db6.png

Comment: what about: `if(s.indexof(__dirname)==0) s.substring(__dirname.length);`

Comment: gp, no good because i dont know if the paths change once i upload them. i could test but if they change things later ill have to do this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex example is wrong. The regex is for removing backslash. But the string itself does not have either backslash or slash.

```
var y = "c:\y";
//"c:y"
```

To correctly add backslash you have to

```
var y = "c:\\y";
//"c:\y"
```

Your example would have worked in linux where the separator is /, which does not need to be escaped. Besides it looks like you are doing substring replace not regex replace. So simply giving the __dirname in replace would suffice :

```
var y = __dirname;
var z = y.replace(__dirname,"").toString();
```

Comment: If you want to search a string via regex see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @user1873073 You are printing y, print z.